# Computer hard freezes when I click battery or sound icon, or display settings

Tags: windows-10, freeze, battery, display-settings

I have a 2014 Razer Blade laptop with nothing plugged in to it. I have the latest windows updates and graphics card updates.

If I click on the battery icon to try to see battery life (or the sound icon to try to adjust volume) in my taskbar, my laptop instantly freezes permanently. I can still move the mouse. Pressing caps lock still causes the key to light up. I can't do anything else. I have to hard reboot it.

The same thing happens if I right click on the desktop and click "display settings"

It has been like this for about 3 months. Does anybody know a fix? I have already tried disabling all startup services. I have also tried system integrity check. I have 17 GB free on my hard drive.

Similar: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/eae0a57f-32cc-41c1-86a7-aedf1669c302/windows-10-x64-pc-settings-for-display-sound-adjustments-causes-hard-freeze?forum=win10itprogeneral

Comment: Can you open task manager?

Comment: Not when it's frozen. Task Manager does not cause a freeze.

Comment: Have you run `chkdsk /f` from an elevated command prompt?

Comment: Yes I have tried that

Comment: Have you tried `taskkill /im explorer.exe /f` then `explorer.exe` from an elevated command prompt? This restarts the Windows Shell, which will, in turn, restart the taskbar.

Comment: Okay I just tried that. Didn't work.

Comment: How about booting in Safe Mode?

Comment: How about booting in Safe Mode?

Comment: In safe mode there is no battery icon. But I can open the display settings in safe mode only. When I click the sound icon it says Detecting problems then "Troubleshooting couldn't identify the problem"

Comment: Have you tried to use any Antivirus software? I recommend Malwarebytes.

Comment: I've been using Microsoft Security Essentials

Comment: Install Malwarebytes Free, run a scan. After the problem has been fixed, you can uninstall it.